# KivyMD: helper_text, hint_text, and other properties not displaying in MDTextField on screen

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField

class Custom(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = MDScreen(md_bg_color=(0.5, 0, 0.7, 1))  # Set background color here
        text = MDTextField(hint_text="Type something",helper_text="this is helper",pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}, size_hint=(None, None), width=200)
        screen.add_widget(text)
        return screen

Custom().run()
```

I tried doing it on MDBoxLayout and MDScreen but it didnt work. it's only showing a textfield but nothing like the one I saw in tutorials and all. also normal text in textfield shows up but hint_text, helper_text and all doesn't show up on screen. when I add hint_text in the code no error pops up but when helper_text is added it shows an error saying

```
   File "kivy\\_event.pyx", line 243, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__init__
   File "kivy\\_event.pyx", line 235, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__init__
   TypeError: AutoFormatTelephoneNumber.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'helper_text'
```

Without helper text i get this as the output. the output looks kinda weird to me. it doesnt look anything as close as the ones i saw anywhere.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I went over to the documentations on the location where kivyMD was installed. And I found that the syntax was completely different. instead of hint text and helper text I should have written MDTextFieldHintText and MDTextFieldHelperText. although I find this quiet long, I am happy that I finally found a way out :)